# How to extract feeds from random bloggers using blogger api

Tags: python, blogger, gdata, google-api-client

I am using gdata(python) to extract feeds from my blog.
I used [this](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python#RetrievingMetafeed) tutorial as reference.
However, I require the content of a few random public blogs as well.
I read that by substituting `default` with the user Id in

```
query.feed = "/feeds/default/blogs"
```

we can extract feeds from public blogs. I tried that using my friend's user Id and got `feeds not enabled` error.

Is there a way to

1. Access the user Ids available so that I can get the content of random blog?
2. Deal with the `feeds not enabled` error?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please consider giving a little bit more concise information. Show the code snippets you think are problematic and paste the log or error messages you get. That will make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: While trying to access a public blog using query.feed = "/feeds/08739552594105488571/blogs", I received this error:gdata.service.RequestError: {'status': 404, 'body': 'The feed specified by https://www.blogger.com/feeds/08739552594105488571/blogs is not enabled', 'reason': 'Not Found'}. In this case '08739552594105488571' is a valid userId that belongs to my friend. I want to know if there a way to access all the userIds available so that I can extract content from various random public blogs.